# Finish Activity launched from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver which launches a transparent Activity which holds an AlertDialog with 3 buttons.

On each button click, I have set

```
myDialogActivity.this.finish();
```

For me, this has never seemed to work, as I could double tap to bring up recent Activities and have full access to the Activity that I thought I had finished.

After searching on SO, I found the suggestion to add

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

in the Manifest for that Activity. It seems to work in as much as the double tap doesn't show the Activity any more.

My question is why

```
myDialogActivity.this.finish();
```

didn't do what I expected it to do (destroy the Activity so it couldn't be reused). And if

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

is enabling my preferred outcome, do I still need to run

```
myDialogActivity.this.finish();
```

which doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: It finishes your activity. So you might need it to come back to whatever you were doing before the dialog popped up.

Comment: In this case, I don't need to come back to it. The dialog pops up when the app isn't running.